# java.lang.VerifyError when running SolrJClient from IBM Websphere 8 with Java 1.7

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

java.lang.VerifyError when running SolrJClient from IBM Websphere 8 with Java 1.7. Anyone experienced same? Any Fix suggestions other than recompiling the SolrJClient?

> java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil, method=createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient;, pc=61